# Making a dataframe out of a condition on one of the columns; need to know the right syntax

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got a big dataframe where in the fifth column are date/time stamps, and I want to filter by the condition of the fifth and sixth character being "01" (so as to get the month of January).

My first attempt at the right syntax was

```
df_b_january=df_b.loc[df_b[4][4:6]=="01"]
```

Where df_b is the big dataframe, and df_b_january is a smaller dataframe consisting only of those rows of the first dataframe such that the substring of the fifth column with the index range given is "01". And yeah, I get that this is too memory-intensive a way to do it, but right now I'm just hoping to master the correct syntax for this, assuming it can be done in one line. It gives an error message at the moment, but presumably if it were a condition referring to the whole string that would be all right. Is there a way to do it in just one line?

Comment: Maybe it'll be useful to include the error message in your post.

Maybe you can use a regular expression [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) to match these characters in your string?

Comment: `df_b.loc[df_b.iloc[:, 4].str[4:6] == "01"]` with `iloc` choosing 5th column positionally then with `str` accessor slicing needed characters. You might also want to convert this column to datetime and filter with `df_b.iloc[:, 4].dt.month == 1`.

Comment: Mustafa's suggestion does successfully solve the problem, so I think him for that, and I also will take on board fravolt's point that it's probably good to include error messages in the future.